# Performing operation on multiple columns with data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I having trouble figuring out how to perform multiple operations in `data.table` using some patterns matching to determine which columns are used. For example:

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:data.table':
#> 
#>     between, first, last
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)

iris <- copy(iris)

iris_dplyr_above_6 <- iris %>% 
  select(contains("Length"), Species) %>% 
  gather(col, val, -Species) %>% 
  filter(val > 6) 

unique(iris_dplyr_above_6$Species)
#> [1] versicolor virginica 
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica


setDT(iris)
iris_dt_above_6 <- iris[Sepal.Length > 6 | Petal.Length > 6,]
unique(iris_dt_above_6$Species)
#> [1] versicolor virginica 
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In this example I can select columns with `dplyr` based on the "Length" string. In `data.table` I have to manually enter each column. Obviously this example is trivial as typing out two column names is hardly onerous. However, in situations where you have many many columns, having some programmatic way to select your columns is useful. I am assuming that `data.table` has a nifty way of doing this and I just haven't been able to find it yet. Or maybe I am misunderstanding the problem and really it is a base R solution.

Any advice?

Comment: In this example, you use `gather` to convert the data to a longer format. The `data.table` equivalent is `melt`. The R-FAQ about [converting from wide to long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/903061) shows many methods, including both `gather` and `melt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
melt(iris, id="Species", measure=patterns("Length"))[value > 6, unique(Species)]
```

*How it works.* I'm not very familiar with tidyr, but... `melt` corresponds to `gather` and the `measure.vars` arg allows selection of columns, possible multiple groups of them, like, `patterns("Length", "Width")`.

*Context.* The `melt` syntax is inherited from the reshape2 package, originally developed by the same people as dplyr, tidyr, et al. [`gather` is soon to be replaced](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2019/03/tidyverse-users-gather-spread-are-on-the-way-out/) with `pivot_longer` in case you're interested in continuing with it. It sounds like it will eventually also have the `patterns()` functionality.